# NS2 Simulation for Wireless Sensor Networks

Tags: simulation, wireless, sensors, ns2

I have a simulation project for wireless sensor networks. In the project I'm suppose to simulate two WSN protocols for performance and security. Protocols like ZigBEE, SPINS. Tinysec, LEDS, LiSIP. Any two from the list. The simulation is to be done in NS2. I don't know how and where to start? For simulation I need working codes for the protocols, how to I write the codes? I meant how should approach to write them or will I get it online.

Comment: I have same problem too, why no one help!!!!!!
[MY QUESTION][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24590638/how-to-run-a-gpsr-project-in-ns2